# Python: Installing pygresql

Tags: python-3.x, pygresql

I am trying to install PyGreSQL module on my computer using pip. It shows this message:
   `Collecting pygresql
    Using cached PyGreSQL-5.0.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
    Installing collected packages: pygresql
    Successfully installed pygresql-5.0.3`
But when I try to import it the very next message is this

```
>>> import pygresql
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named 'pygresql'
 >>> from pygresql import _pg
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ImportError: No module named 'pygresql'
```

Answer (score 0):

its `pg` as in `from pg import DB` according to the documentation on their site.

Comment: `>>> from pg import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      
g.py", line 32, in <module>
    from _pg import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. `

Comment: It is case specific: `DB`.

Comment: Yeah. Tried that too. It isn't working. It says it doesn't recognize the module pygresql

Comment: Seems like this could be a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628836/ver-2-pygresql-error-from-pg-import-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specif/28631274#28631274

You likely don't have PostgreSQL itself installed.

Comment: Yes. I was planning to use this driver to access RedShift database and not PostGreSQL

Comment: Its still required or at least some kind of supported database driver is, Amazon has its own RedShift drivers but if you aren't using theirs just grab the PostGreSQL installation package; there is a DLL included that it needs.

Comment: The installer is here: https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Installation instructions for pygresql: http://www.pygresql.org/contents/install.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem after reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628836/ver-2-pygresql-error-from-pg-import-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specif?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The first error I faced was not having compatible versions of `postgresql` and `python.`
The second error was not having right path variables set.

Hope this helps someone with the same issue. Thank you guys :)