# ERROR: from _pg import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, postgresql, dll

I'm having the exact same problem as described here:
[ver.2 PyGreSQL ERROR: from _pg import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628836/ver-2-pygresql-error-from-pg-import-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specif)

the error:

> from _pg import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I'm using :

```
Python 2.7.3 64 bit
PygreSQL 4.1  (installed into C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ )
PostgreSQL 9.3.3 64 bit
Windows 7
```

I tried to fix the issue as listed in the answer but it doesn't work.
Environment variables (PATH) are set:

```
C:\PostgreSQL;C:\PostgreSQL\9.3;C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

PostgreSQL was installed to :

```
C:\PostgreSQL
```

`_pg.pyd` exists as said there.

However I still get the same error.

I should note that when I open a comand line and do:

```
import pg
import _pg
```

everything works.

What can still be the issue?

Comment: what is the *actual* python version that you use to run the command, vs. the python that you run from command line - you can prepend your script with `import sys; print(sys.version)` - this string should be the same as the one from console.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think this has something to do with the PygreSQL. On one computer it works... but on the other i see that the pg.connect is marked with error: Undefined variable from import: connect   it is like he isn't able to import the pg library

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed on your computer?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? Running into the same issue.