# pgdb import error (_pd.pyd file not created)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pgdb

Facing the same issue as [ver.2 PyGreSQL ERROR: from _pg import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628836/ver-2-pygresql-error-from-pg-import-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specif), but in this case I can see that _pg.pyd file is not created in the site packages of the virtual environment.

```
import pg
  File "c:\users\pmlp\.virtualenvs\qc-scheduling-nfxvviij\lib\site-packages\pgdb.py", line 68, in <module>
from _pg import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any idea how I can create it or why it is not created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I just needed to add the postgree path to the user path:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin;%PATH%
```